# onActivityResult don't take data back in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult

I have 80 different `Buttons` with different IDs so i set `android:"onClick" = addMateria;` but the problem is that i use Fragment and he can't see the method addMateria inside `Fragment`.

So i put the method inside the `Activity` that contain the `Fragment`.
This method invoke startActvityForResult and the Fragment take the data back.

The problem is that the Fragment don't take nothing back.
I read some post that suggest to use `super.onActivityResult`or simple call `StartActivityForResult` but nothing change!

The method inside the Activity that manage all Fragments

```
public void addMateria(View v){

        /* Prendo il nome della risorsa cosi nel ricompilare il progetto non perdo *
         * tutti i riferimenti ai bottoni salvati nel database                     */

        clickedButtonViewId = getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());


        //StartActivityForResult perche mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DialogAddMateria.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
        //onStop();
    }
```

This is the onActivityResult inside the Fragment

```
//Take back data from ActivityAddMateria
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());

                //Cambio subito il Button
                int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(clickedButtonViewId, "id", getActivity().getPackageName());
                final Button clickedtextView = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(resId);

                String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Take the materia from Dialog
                int color = data.getIntExtra("color", 1); //Take the color from Dialog

                //Controllo se il Button è già presente nel db se presente aggiorno se non presente inserisco
                boolean modifica = db.Exists(clickedButtonViewId);

                //Se voglio ripristinare il bottone di default
                if (color == getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_orario)) {

                    //Ripristino la grafica di Default
                    Drawable style = setButtonColor(color);
                    clickedtextView.setBackground(style);
                    clickedtextView.setText("New");

                    //Se la materia è nel database la cancello
                    if (modifica) {

                        db.deleteSingleMateria(clickedButtonViewId);

                    }

                } else {
                    //Quando inserisco un normale bottone colorato
                    if (!modifica) {

                        //Materia da inserire in un nuovo spazio
                        db.addMateriaToDb(new Materia(clickedButtonViewId, result, color));

                    } else {

                        //Materia già presente nel Button quindi aggiorno la materia
                        db.updateMateria(new Materia(clickedButtonViewId, result, color));
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Materia modificata!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    //Inserisco la materia nel DB dei voti_media
                    db.addMateriaVotiFromOrario(new MaterieVoti(result, 0.0));

                    clickedtextView.setText(result);
                    //clickedtextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    //clickedtextView.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    Drawable style = setButtonColor(color);
                    clickedtextView.setBackground(style);
                }
            }

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Nessuna materia inserita
            }

        }
    }//onActivityResult
```

Why the method don't start and i can't save received data inside database?

**What i have:**
A Fragment that it's view is composed with 80 Buttons with a method onClick that start an Activity for result.
This method start a dialogActivity that take data from user and send back with onActivityResult to the Fragment

**The problem:**
The method addMateria called with onClick inside xml it's impossible to declare it directly inside fragment, and if i declare it inside Activity that contain Fragment the onActivityResult don't take back the data from Dialog, so i think that if the method start from Activity the connection between startActivityForResult(inside Activity) and onAcitivtyResult(inside Fragment) is lost.

The only/best way it's with Interface?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pass data between a fragment and an activity, and vice versa, I recommend using interfaces.

To use interfaces, I would modify your code like so:

First define the interface.

```
public interface FragmentCommunication {
    void onAddMateriaClicked(/* Add item(s) you wish to be passed here*/);
}
```

Then Implement said interface in your fragment, replacing the code you had in the `onActivityResult` method in our overriden `onAddMateriaClicked` method:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunication {
    //...
    @Override
    public void onAddMateriaClicked() {
        if(requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());

                //Cambio subito il Button
                int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(clickedButtonViewId, "id", getActivity().getPackageName());
                final Button clickedtextView = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(resId);

                String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Take the materia from Dialog
                int color = data.getIntExtra("color", 1); //Take the color from Dialog

                //Controllo se il Button è già presente nel db se presente aggiorno se non presente inserisco
                boolean modifica = db.Exists(clickedButtonViewId);

                //Se voglio ripristinare il bottone di default
                if (color == getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_orario)) {

                    //Ripristino la grafica di Default
                    Drawable style = setButtonColor(color);
                    clickedtextView.setBackground(style);
                    clickedtextView.setText("New");

                    //Se la materia è nel database la cancello
                    if (modifica) {

                        db.deleteSingleMateria(clickedButtonViewId);

                    }

                } else {
                    //Quando inserisco un normale bottone colorato
                    if (!modifica) {

                        //Materia da inserire in un nuovo spazio
                        db.addMateriaToDb(new Materia(clickedButtonViewId, result, color));

                    } else {

                        //Materia già presente nel Button quindi aggiorno la materia
                        db.updateMateria(new Materia(clickedButtonViewId, result, color));
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Materia modificata!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    //Inserisco la materia nel DB dei voti_media
                    db.addMateriaVotiFromOrario(new MaterieVoti(result, 0.0));

                    clickedtextView.setText(result);
                    //clickedtextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    //clickedtextView.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    Drawable style = setButtonColor(color);
                    clickedtextView.setBackground(style);
                }
            }

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Nessuna materia inserita
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we modify our activity to call the `onAddMateriaClicked` method when the button has been clicked:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private FragmentCommunication communication;
    private MyFragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragment = new MyFragment();
        communication = fragment;
    }

    public void addMateria(View v) {
        /* Prendo il nome della risorsa cosi nel ricompilare il progetto non perdo *
         * tutti i riferimenti ai bottoni salvati nel database                     */

        clickedButtonViewId = getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());


        communication.onAddMateriaClicked();
        //onStop();
    }
}
```

Now `onAddMateriaClicked` will be called within the fragment when you hit your button.

Make sure you add whatever data you wish to pass as parameters to the `onAddMateriaClicked` item.

Comment: Hi Weava, thanks for your suggestion.
I will try your method, but anyway i can't put the method addMateria inside Fragment without interface?
Or it's the only way?

Comment: The onClick function must be designated to a view within the same activity or fragment as it is declared. If your button is in the Activity, then you have to have some sort of method for sending that data up to the attached fragment. There are other ways, but I find this is the cleanest.

Comment: Yes the onClick function is in the view of the fragment not in the Activity.
The view with all Buttons with onClick method is managed by Fragment that inside him the onclick method call a Dialog_Activity that return some data....but anyway i can't declare the method inside Fragment_class.